# Display images as thumbnail and then download Struts2

Tags: java, file-io, struts2, download

I am trying to view an image which is not in the application but in other drive. but i am not getting the output, my action is not getting called. please point out the mistake.

**jsp**

```
<img src="<s:url var="profilePic" action="download">
                    <s:param name="fid" value="test"/>
                  </s:url>" alt="logo" />
```

**action**

```
       public class DownloadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{
        private HttpServletRequest req;

     @Action(value="download", results = { @Result(location="/index.jsp", type="stream", 
             params={"contentType","application/octet-stream","inputName","fileInputStream","bufferSize","1024"}
             ), @Result(name="input", location="/index.jsp")
        })
    public String download() throws Exception {
            //File theFile = new File("c:\\shareapp\\admin",getReq().getParameter("fid"));
         try{
             System.out.println("inside");
                FileInputStream inputStream=FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("c:\\shareapp\\admin",getReq().getParameter("fid")));
         }catch(Exception ce)
         {
             System.out.println(ce);
         }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
//getters & setters
```

Actually i want the file to be loaded as thumbnail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You **think** your action is not being called? Why not to test it and then ask a question.

Comment: I used this System.out.println("inside"); and no output on console so its not getting called

Comment: sorry and changed in question also :)

Comment: I added the action to <a> tag. <a href="download">test</a> but the same is not working from image tag. :(

Comment: anything in the logs? or what happening when u clicked on the anchor?

Comment: nothing in logs, anchor is working, its downloading the file

Comment: how it's downloading if it's nothing in logs :)

Comment: i gave like this now <img src="<s:url action='download' />" alt="logo" height="100" width="100"/> and its working but not along with param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use `<s:url>` tag like that then remove `var` attribute. And if `<s:param>` `value` attribute is string then use `'` to show that it is string.

```
<img src="<s:url action="download">
            <s:param name="fid" value="'test'"/>
          </s:url>" alt="logo" />
```